# Parsing cell value of Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, spreadsheet, openxml-sdk

I parse cell located in **A2** address. This returns **3** value instead of the expected **Category 1**.

[test.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMVzwY6KDv61Ar81n565NgSZOUpNKghp/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using X = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace DotNetSandbox.SO
{
    public class IncorrectCellValue
    {
        public static void ParseCellValue()
        {
            using SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"c:\temp\test.xlsx", false);
            X.Sheet sheet = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<X.Sheet>().First();
            WorksheetPart wsPart = (WorksheetPart)doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
            X.Cell cell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<X.Cell>().First(c => c.CellReference == "A2");

            string cellValue = cell.CellValue.Text;

            Console.WriteLine(cellValue);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> 3

---

- Target: .NET 5
- DocumentFormat.OpenXml version: 2.13.0

I do something wrong or maybe is it a library bug?

Comment: Use **[ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)** package instead. It is a lightweight and fast library written in C# for reading Microsoft Excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method

```
 public static string GetCellValue(string fileName,
        string addressName, string sheetName = "")
    {
        string value = null;

        // Open the spreadsheet document for read-only access.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document =
            SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            // Retrieve a reference to the workbook part.
            WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

            // Find the sheet with the supplied name, and then use that 
            // Sheet object to retrieve a reference to the first worksheet.
            var theSheets = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>();
            Sheet theSheet = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName) ? theSheets.FirstOrDefault() : theSheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == sheetName);

            // Throw an exception if there is no sheet.
            if (theSheet == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sheetName");
            }

            // Retrieve a reference to the worksheet part.
            WorksheetPart wsPart =
                (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));

            // Use its Worksheet property to get a reference to the cell 
            // whose address matches the address you supplied.
            Cell theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
              Where(c => c.CellReference == addressName).FirstOrDefault();

            // If the cell does not exist, return an empty string.
            if (theCell.InnerText.Length > 0)
            {
                value = theCell.InnerText;

                // If the cell represents an integer number, you are done. 
                // For dates, this code returns the serialized value that 
                // represents the date. The code handles strings and 
                // Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code 
                // looks up the corresponding value in the shared string 
                // table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into 
                // the words TRUE or FALSE.
                if (theCell.DataType != null)
                {
                    switch (theCell.DataType.Value)
                    {
                        case CellValues.SharedString:

                            // For shared strings, look up the value in the
                            // shared strings table.
                            var stringTable =
                                wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                            // If the shared string table is missing, something 
                            // is wrong. Return the index that is in
                            // the cell. Otherwise, look up the correct text in 
                            // the table.
                            if (stringTable != null)
                            {
                                value =
                                    stringTable.SharedStringTable
                                    .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                            }
                            break;

                        case CellValues.Boolean:
                            switch (value)
                            {
                                case "0":
                                    value = "FALSE";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    value = "TRUE";
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

You stuck here:

> If the cell represents an integer number, you are done.
> For dates, this code returns the serialized value that
> represents the date. The code handles strings and
> Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code
> looks up the corresponding value in the shared string
> table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into
> the words TRUE or FALSE.

I was able to get Category 1 by running this code:

```
 var cellValue = GetCellValue(@"c:\test.xlsx", "A2");
```

[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-cells-in-a-spreadsheet#calling-the-getcellvalue-sample-method)

Notice that I changed the original method to get the first sheet if you do not pass the sheet name to the method.

**What is Shared String:**
To optimize the use of strings in a spreadsheet, SpreadsheetML stores a single instance of the string in a table called the shared string table. The cells then reference the string by index instead of storing the value inline in the cell value. Excel always creates a shared string table when it saves a file.